# Detecting element on which the user has clicked from mozilla firefox extension

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web, firefox-addon

I am developing a mozilla firefox extension. I have a sample web page in which i have embedded an iframe with some web page loaded in it. User can click anywhere but i want to alert the user whenever he clicks on the iframe part. All the processing is to be done from my extension only.plz help..

Comment: See [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target)

Answer (score 0):

```
iframe.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target) {
var win = e.target.ownerDocument.defaultView;
win.alert('you clicked on ' + e.target);
}
}
```

Comment: it is giving error "ReferenceError: iframe is not defined".

Comment: you have to get the iframe first man. so probably like `var iframe = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').gBrowser.selectedTab.linkedBrowser.contentDocument.getElementById('THE ID OF THE IFRAME');`

Comment: and how to get ID of the iframe?

Comment: oh actually instead of id of the iframe, (i dont htink it has one), do `getElementsByTagName('iframe')`, there should only be one iframe in the panel

Comment: illegal character error is coming in the following code                var iframe = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').gBrowser.selectedTab.linked‌​Browser.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('iframe');          

iframe.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target) {
 var win = e.target.ownerDocument.defaultView;
 win.alert('you clicked on ' + e.target);
 }
 },false);

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a collection. so you have to go `iframe[0].addEventListener`

Comment: i tried what u said but its giving same error. The error is because of this sentence var iframe = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').gBrowser.selectedTab.linked‌​‌​Browser.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('iframe');   and i think because of that linkedBrowser part as far as i experimented.

Comment: see if this line works: ``Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').gBrowser.selectedTab.linkedBrowser.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName)`

Comment: whats the difference between this line and the previous one?

Comment: This one just checks if your document has the `getElementsByTagName` function

Comment: i have written this line in my .js file. ``Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').gBrowser.selectedTab.linke‌​dBrowser.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('iframe')` but again giving error "illegal character" in the browser console.

Comment: gosh lol ok. upload your project onto github then share link with me